# How to change color picker appearance in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color

[image]

[image]

At some point my color picker switched to this. (first image) I find it really hard to use. How do I change it back (to image 2), any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

Tick the **H** (Hue) option......

[image]

Your first image is set to **B** for *blue*...

You *really* don't need the color picker in Illustrator though. All the options are in the **Color Panel**, which you have open on the right.

Comment: Your mileage may vary. I greatly prefer the 'picker myself.